# How to match 5 rows with one row from another sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm not searching for VBA solution but Excel formula one or any trick which might be helfpul.

Problem is following:

Sheet Main has in cell A1 reference number 1TF1234 and in cell A2 1TF5678.

Sheet Parties is empty and I want to create formula to populate cells A1 to A5 with value from cell A1 Main sheet and then A6 to A10 with value from cell A2 Main sheet and so on.

Main
A1 - 1TF1234
A2 - 1TF5678

Parties
A1 - 1TF1234
A2 - 1TF1234
A3 - 1TF1234
 
A4 - 1TF1234
 
A5 - 1TF1234
A6 - 1TF5678
A7 - 1TF5678
A8 - 1TF5678
A9 - 1TF5678
A10 - 1TF5678

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX with a little math:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/5)+1)
```

[image]

---

If one has the Dynamic array formula SEQUENCE we can Spill the results with:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)*5,,0)/5)+1)
```

[image]